# Dump handles of Windows process and extra information about them

Tags: windows, debugging, dump, window-handles

today my application throw a "no more handles" error on Windows, while allocating an image. To debug this I would love to get a list of all handles my application has aquired. If possible even with type, like font, image or whatever, and include the information in my error report to see where my application leaks.

I use Java and SWT, but have no problem with calling native functions or a third-party application to fetch the information in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) was the tool I needed! It is even scriptable, so the output can be used in bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

For a utility, try *Process Explorer* from Microsoft [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/). This will show process strings, handles, files, parents, threads, thread stacks, etc., etc.

Comment: Yes, this is really a great tool. I would love if it would be scriptable, so I can send its output by mail.

Comment: _Process Explorer_ seems to be a lot of the other utilities wrapped up into one GUI thingy. Have a look at _Handle_ for instance, a command-line app. (Its docs even say "You can also get a GUI-based version of this program, Process Explorer, here at Sysinternals.")